# Cannot bind selected checkbox items to model MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this class of Status :

```
public class Status
    {
        public Status(int id, string description)
        {
            Id = id;
            Description = description;
        }


        public int  Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    }
```

This is my Model:

```
public class StatusModel
{
    public StatusModel()
    {
        Statuses = new List<Status>();
    }
    public List<Status> Statuses { get; set; }

}
```

and my View looks like this:

```
@model MVCTestApplication.Models.StatusModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("TestView", "Home"))
{
 <table>
 <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>
           Status
           </th>
       </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Statuses.Count(); i++)
 {
 <tr>
 <td>

 @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Statuses[i].IsChecked, new { @id = Model.Statuses[i].Id })

 @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Statuses[i].Description, Model.Statuses[i].Description)

 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Statuses[i].Description)

 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Statuses[i].Id)

 </td>
 </tr>
 }

</tbody>
</table>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

and in controller I have:

```
public ActionResult TestView(StatusModel statuses)
{
//.......
}
```

I need to select all checked checkbox items, but when i wrote such code, I get null for my statuses variable in controller. And I don't know what I did wrong

Comment: is this your complete TestView Action code?

Comment: not, in this controller contains a single line of code  `return View(statuses);`

Comment: where are you adding items in the statuses list?

Comment: I read it from database

Comment: post that action as well

Comment: `private DataTable ReadStatus(string connectionString)
        {
                SqlConnection conn = new                             SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM Statuses";
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();

            return ds.Tables[0];
        }`

Comment: `private List<Status> DataTableToStatus(DataTable table)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
                int id = (int)table.Rows[i].ItemArray[0];
                string desc = (string)table.Rows[i].ItemArray[1];
                statuses.Add(new Status(id, desc));
            }
            return statuses;
        }`

Comment: add it in the question by editing in well format its not easily readable

Comment: With this methods I read data

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841428/how-to-bind-checkbox-values-to-a-list-of-ints/21842127#21842127 for an example of how to bindto checkboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to do something like this, read from db and pass to view:

```
public ActionResult TestView()
{
DataTable datatable = ReadStatus("yourconnectionstring");
List<Status> statuses = DataTableToStatus(datatable);
StatusModel model = new StatusModel();

model.Statuses = statuses 
return View(Statuses);
}


private DataTable ReadStatus(string connectionString) 
{ 
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand(); 
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM Statuses"; 
da.SelectCommand = cmd; 
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
conn.Open(); 
da.Fill(ds); 
conn.Close(); 
return ds.Tables[0]; 
} 

private List<Status> DataTableToStatus(DataTable table) 
{ 
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++) 
{ 
int id = (int)table.Rows[i].ItemArray[0];
string desc = (string)table.Rows[i].ItemArray[1];
statuses.Add(new Status(id, desc)); 
} 

return statuses; 
}
```

and here is your action on which data model will be posted:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestView(ModelStatus model)
{
// your business logic here
}
```

In view set httpmethod to post:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestView", "Home",HttpMethod="POST"))
{
 <table>
 <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>
           Status
           </th>
       </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Statuses.Count(); i++)
 {
 <tr>
 <td>

 @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Statuses[i].IsChecked, new { @id = Model.Statuses[i].Id })

 @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Statuses[i].Description, Model.Statuses[i].Description)

 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Statuses[i].Description)

 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Statuses[i].Id)

 </td>
 </tr>
 }
```

Comment: It works but I have other problem. When I check some checkboxes on page and press button I get list of all check buttons

Comment: yes it will post the checkboxes values which are checked not the ones that are not checked

Comment: i think it will post null values against the ones not checked

Comment: for example I have 5 check boxes and when I select 2. I want to post those elements, but currently I post all of this

Comment: whole model will be posted on action, you have to filter them in action before doing any db operation according to your business logic