# CheckBox lists in ASP.NET MVC and bind it back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 Html.CheckBox("SelectedStudents", false, new { @class = "check-item", id = x.Id, value = x.Id })
```

which produce

```
<input checked="checked" class="check-item" id="4507" name="SelectedStudents" value="4507" type="checkbox">

<input checked="checked" class="check-item" id="4507" name="SelectedStudents" value="4508" type="checkbox">

<input checked="checked" class="check-item" id="4507" name="SelectedStudents" value="4509" type="checkbox">
```

In mvc model I have

```
public IEnumerable<string> SelectedStudents { get; set; }
```

but when I post back, SelectedStudents are always null. Why?
In this howto http://benfoster.io/blog/checkbox-lists-in-aspnet-mvc
is written:

> The ASP.NET MVC modelbinder is smart enough to map the selected items
>   to this property.

but in my example is always null. Why? How to write more checkboxes and bind it back

Comment: Because the blog you posted is using a strongly typed Editor (strongly typed editors end in *For* like `CheckListBoxFor`) and you changed it to use a dumb editor (`Checkbox`).  Dumb editors can be model bound back as long as you know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 12):

You should be using a strongly typed editor to be able to pass the result to the controller (Model binder).

I prefer to do it this way.

**Model**

```
public class YourViewModel
{
     public List<SelectListItem> Students
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}
```

**Controller Get**

```
Students= service.GetStudents(); //Fill the list
```

**View**

```
  @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Students.Count; i++)
                {

                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Students[i].Selected)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Students[i].Text)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Students[i].Value)
                    <span>@Model.Students[i].Text</span>
                }
```

**Controller Post**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(YourViewModel model)
        {
          foreach(var student in model.Students)
          {
            if(student.Selected) { // Do your logic}
          }
        }
```

*Alternatively* 
You could use an array or List of string. *A ListBox is used in this example.*

```
public string[] SelectedStudents{ get; set; }

@Html.ListBoxFor(s => s.SelectedStudents, new MultiSelectList(Model.Students, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedStudents), new { @class = "form-control", style = "height:250px; width:100%" })
```

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here [How to bind checkbox values to a list of ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841428/how-to-bind-checkbox-values-to-a-list-of-ints/21842127#21842127).

The nice thing about this is that it separates concerns between your controller and ui nicely.  The html extension methods also create correct html using label and input for the checkbox. and there is no need for hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try it with CheckBoxListFor?? You need to associate the checkbox with model and should not have the same ID and name

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(model => model.SelectedSources, Model.SubscriptionSources)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a mutable type, like `List<string>`.

```
public List<string> SelectedStudents { get; set; }
```